# Why wasn't Darth Maul able to react to Obi-Wans final attack?

Tags: star-wars

I understand that Darth Maul was overconfident.
I understand that Obi-Wans Force Jump and calling of Qui-Gons weapon was meant as a suprise to Darth Maul.

What I do not understand is, while in a fight the jedi and sith show us incredible fast Reflexes strikes and counterstrikes. Aided by the force (precognition and fast moving).
If I remember the Scene correctly, Obi-Wan jumps out of the hole, jumps and saltoes over darth maul while grabbing and activating Qui-Gons weapon.
But instead of an immediate fluid strike out of the same move, we see a stunned and disbelieving Darth Maul, and a still Standing  Obi-Wan who waits a full second before striking Darth Maul to peaces.

Why did Obi-Wan wait a full second? I think even out of universe it would have been as rule of cool if the strike was even while he was still saltoing over darth maul.

Darth Maul surely could be surprised a split second. But it seems highly unrealistic to me that he stood there frozen a full second, and no trained combat reflex kicked in, instinctivly blocking the strike. He was even able to turn around.

Edit:

I do not think its a duplicate. The "original" inspired me to ask this question. It states:

> Even as he landed, he was drawing Qui-Gon Jinn’s fallen lightsaber to
>   his outstretched hand.

In the movie here is a full second nobody moves.

> Darth Maul whirled to confront him, shock and rage twisting his red
>   and black face. **But before he could act to save himself**, Qui-Gon’s
>   lightsaber slashed through his chest, burning him with killing fire.

And I don't understand while the strike was "before he could act". Because in the movie he was able to turn around, Obi Wan waited a full second (why?) Darth Maul only looked surprised (a full second surprise? An experiences Fighter? So surprised that his trained reflexes don't let him block this simple strike that he had to wait for a full second?)

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10681/31051 and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/89307/31051

Comment: Because he's a schmuck

Comment: @Richard I’m not so convinced this is really a duplicate of that question (or more specifically, your answer to it). The only relevant part of the quotes in your answer is really the phrasing “But before he could act to save himself”, and that is clearly at odds with the movie, where Maul is given _plenty_ of time (for an advanced Force user) to act to save himself. The novelisation doesn’t mention the hesitation and lack of reaction that the movie shows. The first of the two questions linked to by Jason is a better dupe candidate, I’d say.

Comment: In fact the question you think I duplicate inspired me to ask this question. But I ask especially about this odd long time that both Obi-Wan and Darth Maul do nothing. I even don't understand it OOU because an immediate strike while still in the air would both be cool for the audience and also completely plausible that Maul can not block because of his surprise. But in the movie Obi-Wan stands behind him, Maul has time to move around and look surprised, all combat Reflexes paralysed and after a full second Obi strikes him and he has no block. Suprised or not, the block should have be a Reflex.

Comment: Darth Sidious was on Naboo and used the force to petrify Maul so Obi-Wan could kill him.  All part of his elaborate plan to groom Anakin.